# Adjust Longtable to textwidth

Tags: longtable

I have a problem with the adjustment of my longtables to textwidth. I use tables with a different number of columns, and apparently LaTeX fails to adjust them to the same width. All Longtables with the same number of colums are displayed with the same width. How can I solve this problem?
Thanks in advance!

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,headsepline,american]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\captionsetup{format=plain,font=footnotesize}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{layouts}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\begin{document}
...

\begin{longtable}{|>{\RaggedRight}p{0.4\textwidth}|>{\RaggedRight}p{0.2\textwidth}|>{\RaggedRight}p{0.4\textwidth}|}
\caption[...]{\textbf{...}}\\
\hline
... & ...   & ...\\
\hline
\hline
\endfirsthead
\hline
... & ...   & ...\\
\hline
\hline
\endhead
... & ...& ...\\
\hline
\end{longtable}

...

\begin{longtable}{|>{\RaggedRight}p{0.3\textwidth}|>{\RaggedRight}p{0.7\textwidth}|}
\caption[...]{\textbf{...}}\\
\hline
...     & ...\\
\hline
\hline
\endfirsthead
\hline
...     & ...\\
\hline
\hline
\endhead
...     & ...\\
\hline
\end{longtable}

...
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to account for the widths of the rules (`\arrayrulewidth`) and column padding (`\tabcolsep` on each side of the column) so:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,headsepline,american]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\captionsetup{format=plain,font=footnotesize}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{layouts}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\newlength\ltlen

\begin{document}
...

\setlength\ltlen{\dimexpr\textwidth-4\arrayrulewidth-6\tabcolsep}
\begin{longtable}{|>{\RaggedRight}p{0.4\ltlen}|>{\RaggedRight}p{0.2\ltlen}|>{\RaggedRight}p{0.4\ltlen}|}
\caption[...]{\textbf{...}}\\
\hline
... & ...   & ...\\
\hline
\hline
\endfirsthead
\hline
... & ...   & ...\\
\hline
\hline
\endhead
... & ...& ...\\
\hline
\end{longtable}

...

\setlength\ltlen{\dimexpr\textwidth-3\arrayrulewidth-4\tabcolsep}
\begin{longtable}{|>{\RaggedRight}p{0.3\ltlen}|>{\RaggedRight}p{0.7\ltlen}|}
\caption[...]{\textbf{...}}\\
\hline
...     & ...\\
\hline
\hline
\endfirsthead
\hline
...     & ...\\
\hline
\hline
\endhead
...     & ...\\
\hline
\end{longtable}

...
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! But the tables are now a lot wider that the actual textwidth, which is indicated by the length of the header etc. Also, I have some more tables with different column numbers, so what is the general rule behind the numbers in the line \setlength\ltlen{\dimexpr\textwidth-4\arrayrulewidth-6\tabcolsep}?

Comment: @ke.sijing the tables in the above are _exactly_ textwidth wide so I don't understand your comment about them being wider than the text width. the numbers are the numbers of rules in the table and twice the number of columms. Each rule is \arrayrulewidth wide so if you have four rules you need to allow for that before allocating space to the columns, each column has \tabcolsep space either side so if you have 3 columns that is 6\tabcolspace that must be accounted for.

Comment: Yeah, the tables in your example have the same width. But this is not the case for the tables in my document, for whatever reason...

Comment: ok, found my syntax error, everything works now. :) Thank you!